# ios UIScrollview wont change height

Tags: ios, uiview, resize

The application is a simple UIScrollView that consists of a iCarousel UIView and under that view is another view. I want the iCarousel view to change height while I'm scrolling down, however the

```
float scrollableArea = scrollView.contentSize.height - self.view.layer.bounds.size.height - 44;//naviagtion bar height 
float yPercentPosition = (scrollView.contentOffset.y / scrollableArea) * 100;

CGRect frame = carousel.frame;
frame.size.height = frame.size.height - yPercentPosition;
carousel.frame = frame;
```

way, doesn't seem to work and I dont have a clue why. It looks like the iCarousel view even got bigger.

Comment: How is `yPercentPosition` generated?

Comment: like this: `float scrollableArea = scrollView.contentSize.height - self.view.layer.bounds.size.height - 44;
    float yPercentPosition = (scrollView.contentOffset.y / scrollableArea) * 100;` it gets the percent position of the offset basically